# How to return text on the horizontal or vertical edge of a matrix of data in excel

Tags: excel, matrix, excel-formula

I have a matrix of data, with similar values across 5 columns and 5 rows. What I would like the function to do is to return the column text corresponding to where a specific value is. The matrix is dynamic, so there is no fixed cell within the matrix that contains this value, but I know the value from a separate function.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is pivot tables. Pivot tables are super versatile and often overlooked. Here's a great resource for using pivot tables to accomplish what you're looking to achieve [Create a PivotTable to analyze worksheet data](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576).

Tip, if you're going to use a pivot table which I believe is your best solution here, remember to define your data as a table prior to creating a pivot table from it.